# Understanding Set Field Value, Tag Field Value, and Cache Hits/Misses in MIPS Processor

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, processor

I am currently studying computer architecture and I am struggling with a specific exercise involving a 32-bit MIPS processor. The exercise asks to determine the set field value, tag field value, and if the instruction results in a cache hit or miss for each of the six assembly instructions given.

The instructions are as follows:

```
1 lw $t1,0x1040($0)
2 lw $t2,0x2044($0)
3 lw $t3,0x3048($0)
4 lw $t4,0x1044($0)
5 lw $t5,0x504c($0)
6 lw $t6,0x3040($0)
```

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the set field value and tag field value, and then use that information to determine if there is a cache hit or miss.

If anyone could provide any guidance or clarification on this topic, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have tried to understand the concept of set field value and tag field value in a cache memory and how to calculate them for a given address. I expected to be able to use that information to determine if there was a cache hit or miss. However, I am still struggling to fully grasp the concept and apply it to solve the given exercise.

Comment: First, what you're calling set field is more commonly called the index field. Second, to calculate the widths of [tag, index, and offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entry_structure) you need to know certain things about the cache design, and these fields are fixed in width (i.e. static) for a given design, so will not vary based on address accesses.

Comment: What does vary dynamically is the state of the cache, i.e. what is being cached; this varies with the execution of the program, which in the abstract can be seen as a sequence of addresses being accessed.